# pop up window issue in mobile safari

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

i am working on web application which needs to open new browser window for some purpose.i am using JavaScript window.open() method for this.once child window is created using this method i am using window.focus() method to navigate between parent and child window.this works fine on all desktop  and android browser.

code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openWin('url')">
```

to open window:

```
function openWin(url){
    myWindow = window.open(url,"myWindow");   
    myWindow.opener = window;
    myWindow.focus();
}
```

to switch back to parent from child

```
window.opener.focus();
```

switch to child again

```
myWindow.focus();
```

now the problem is when i use it on mobile safari (ipod touch) it shows alert message "This site is attempting to open a pop up window" with options "Allow" and "block". when i click on allow,it opens new window but navigation using window.focus is not working.i think its because safari browser takes it as a pop up window and not full browser window and so it can not return browser object while creation(myWindow).

in this same application i am using same code on click on button and it works on ipod very well with no such alert message, but its not working with anchor tag.

can anyone point me what i should do to make it work,thanks in advance. 
Anil.

Comment: if you don't have accurate answer or time to test on ipod you can give any suggestion over here,i will try it and check if it works.

Comment: Hi @Anil. This is a really old question, but did you have any luck figuring this out? My situation is somewhat similar to this.

Comment: Hey guys, this problem has any solution because I am facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

You may review these GIT issues - [6617](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6617), [5663](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5663), [6864](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6864)

You could try to handle this popup as an Alert. You may try to use following code snippet -

```
// SWITCH TO ALERT    
Alert alert_obj = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
// ACCPET IT
alertObj.accept();
```